# Side-by-side online markdown editor with autoscroll supporting images correctly

Tags: web-apps, markdown

I've tried so far StackEdit, Dillinger and Markable.in, but they all fail when it comes to autoscroll the preview properly when your Markdown includes tall images:

- [Markable.in](http://markable.in/): always scrolls the preview to the bottom
- [Dillinger](http://dillinger.io/): [doesn't autoscroll at all](https://github.com/joemccann/dillinger/issues/132)
- [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/): [scroll doesn't take into account image height](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/777)
- [Hashify](http://hashify.me/): doesn't auto-scroll at all

Comment: Doesn't the [Discourse layout](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253112/the-discourse-layout-for-side-by-side-markdown-preview) do what you want? ;)